# Bidirectional hash map in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, hash-map

I have this bidirectional hash map that allows not just accessing values via keys, but also accessing keys via values. You can find a figure explaining the data structure in this post: [Bidirectional bijective hash map in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166774/bidirectional-bijective-hash-map-in-c).

This is my code:

**BidirectionalHashMap.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.ConcurrentModificationException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class implements a bidirectional hash map mapping keys to values and 
 * values to keys.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 23, 2017)
 * @param <K> the key type.
 * @param <V> the value type.
 */
public final class BidirectionalHashMap<K, V> extends StubMap<K, V> {

    /**
     * This static inner class store all the information for representing a 
     * mapping. Also, it caches the hash codes of both the keys and values in
     * order to avoid recomputing those codes.
     * 
     * @param <K> the key type.
     * @param <V> the value type.
     */
    private static final class Mapping<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {

        /**
         * The key.
         */
        K key;

        /**
         * The value.
         */
        V value;

        /**
         * The hash code of the key.
         */
        int keyHashCode;

        /**
         * The hash code of the value.
         */
        int valueHashCode;

        /**
         * Constructs a new mapping setting the key and the value along their
         * hash codes.
         * 
         * @param key   the key to set.
         * @param value the value to set.
         */
        Mapping(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.keyHashCode = Objects.hashCode(key);
            this.valueHashCode = Objects.hashCode(value);
        }

        @Override
        public K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        @Override
        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public V setValue(V value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("");
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[" + Objects.toString(key) 
                       + " <-> " 
                       + Objects.toString(value) 
                       + "]";
        }
    }

    /**
     * This static inner class implements a collision chain node for keys.
     * 
     * @param <K> the key type.
     * @param <V> the value type.
     */
    private static final class KeyNode<K, V> {

        /**
         * Points to the predecessor node in the collision chain.
         */
        KeyNode<K, V> prev;

        /**
         * Points to the successor node in the collision chain.
         */
        KeyNode<K, V> next;

        /**
         * The actual mapping.
         */
        Mapping<K, V> mapping;

        /**
         * Points to the key that was added to this map immediately <bbefore</b>
         * this node.
         */
        KeyNode<K, V> up;

        /**
         * Points to the key that was added to this map immediately 
         * <b>after</b> this node.
         */
        KeyNode<K, V> down;

        KeyNode(Mapping<K, V> mapping) {
            this.mapping = mapping;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This static inner class implements a collision chain node for the values.
     * 
     * @param <K> the key type.
     * @param <V> the value type.
     */
    private static final class ValueNode<K, V> {

        /**
         * Points to the predecessor node in the collision chain.
         */
        ValueNode<K, V> prev;

        /**
         * Points to the successor node in the collision chain.
         */
        ValueNode<K, V> next;

        /**
         * The actual mapping.
         */
        Mapping<K, V> mapping;

        /**
         * Points to the value that was added to this map immediately 
         * <b>before</b> this node.
         */
        ValueNode<K, V> up;

        /**
         * Points to the value that was added to this map immediately
         * <b>after</b> this node.
         */
        ValueNode<K, V> down;

        ValueNode(Mapping<K, V> mapping) {
            this.mapping = mapping;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The default capacity. Keeping the capacity as powers of two allows us 
     * using bit masking for computing the modulo.
     */
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 8;

    /**
     * The minimum capacity of both the tables.
     */
    private static final int MINIMUM_CAPACITY = 8;

    /**
     * The default load factor.
     */
    private static final float DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR = 1.0f;

    /**
     * The minimum load factor.
     */
    private static final float MINIMUM_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.1f;

    /**
     * The forward hash table mapping keys to the mappings.
     */
    private KeyNode<K, V>[] keyNodes = new KeyNode[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];

    /**
     * The backward hash table mapping values to the mappings.
     */
    private ValueNode<K, V>[] valueNodes = new ValueNode[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];

    /**
     * Points to the oldest key node.
     */
    private KeyNode<K, V> keyIterationHead;

    /**
     * Points to the newest key node.
     */
    private KeyNode<K, V> keyIterationTail;

    /**
     * Points to the oldest value node.
     */
    private ValueNode<K, V> valueIterationHead;

    /**
     * Points to the newest value node.
     */
    private ValueNode<K, V> valueIterationTail;

    /**
     * The number of mappings in this map.
     */
    private int size;

    /**
     * The modification count. Used for failing iteration over map that was 
     * modified during iteration via other than iterator methods.
     */
    private int modificationCount;

    /**
     * The bit mask for simulating modulo arithmetics.
     */
    private int moduloMask = keyNodes.length - 1;

    /**
     * The load factor.
     */
    private final float loadFactor;

    /**
     * The entry set.
     */
    private final EntrySet entrySet = new EntrySet();

    /**
     * The inverse map.
     */
    private final InverseMap inverseMap = new InverseMap();

    public BidirectionalHashMap(float loadFactor, int capacity) {
        this.loadFactor = checkLoadFactor(loadFactor);
        capacity = fixCapacity(capacity);
        this.keyNodes = new KeyNode[capacity];
        this.valueNodes = new ValueNode[capacity];
    }

    public BidirectionalHashMap(float loadFactor) {
        this(loadFactor, DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
    }

    public BidirectionalHashMap(int capacity) {
        this(DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR, capacity);
    }

    public BidirectionalHashMap() {
        this(DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR, DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        modificationCount += size;

        KeyNode<K, V> keyNode = keyIterationHead;

        while (keyNode != null) {
            int index = keyNode.mapping.keyHashCode & moduloMask;
            keyNodes[index] = null;
            keyNode = keyNode.down;
        }

        ValueNode<K, V> valueNode = valueIterationHead;

        while (valueNode != null) {
            int index = valueNode.mapping.valueHashCode & moduloMask;
            valueNodes[index] = null;
            valueNode = valueNode.down;
        }

        size = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return accessKeyNode(key) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return accessValueNode(value) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return entrySet;
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        KeyNode<K, V> keyNode = accessKeyNode(key);
        return keyNode == null ? null : keyNode.mapping.value;
    }

    public Map<V, K> inverseMap() {
        return inverseMap;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if (isFull()) {
            expand();
        }

        KeyNode<K, V> keyNode = accessKeyNode(key);
        V oldValue;

        if (keyNode == null) {
            putNonExisting(key, value);
            oldValue = null;
            size++;
        } else {
            oldValue = updateValue(keyNode, value);
        }

        modificationCount++;
        return oldValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e : m.entrySet()) {
            put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        KeyNode<K, V> keyNode = accessKeyNode(key);

        if (keyNode == null) {
            return null;
        }

        size--;
        modificationCount++;
        return doRemove(keyNode);
    }

    @Override 
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("[");
        String separator = "";

        for (Map.Entry<K, V> e : entrySet()) {
            sb.append(separator);
            separator = ", ";
            sb.append(e);
        }

        return sb.append("]").toString();
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to access the key node containing the input key.
     * 
     * @param key the target key.
     * @return a key node containing the given key or {@code null} if there is
     *         no such.
     */
    private KeyNode<K, V> accessKeyNode(Object key) {
        int inputKeyHashCode = Objects.hashCode(key);
        int inputKeyIndex = inputKeyHashCode & moduloMask;

        for (KeyNode<K, V> node = keyNodes[inputKeyIndex];
                node != null;
                node = node.next) {
            if (node.mapping.keyHashCode == inputKeyHashCode 
                    && Objects.equals(node.mapping.key, key)) {
                return node;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to access the key node containing the given key. This version
     * does not compute the hash code of the input key but rather uses the hash
     * code given in the second argument.
     * 
     * @param key         the target key.
     * @param keyHashCode the hash code of the key.
     * @return a key node containing the given key or {@code null} if there is
     *         no such.
     */
    private KeyNode<K, V> accessKeyNode(Object key, int keyHashCode) {
        int inputKeyIndex = keyHashCode & moduloMask;

        for (KeyNode<K, V> node = keyNodes[inputKeyIndex];
                node != null;
                node = node.next) {
            if (node.mapping.keyHashCode == keyHashCode
                    && Objects.equals(node.mapping.key, key)) {
                return node;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to access the value node containing the input value.
     * 
     * @param value the target value.
     * @return a value node containing the given value or {@code null} if there 
     *         is no such.
     */
    private ValueNode<K, V> accessValueNode(Object value) {
        int inputValueHashCode = Objects.hashCode(value);
        int inputValueIndex = inputValueHashCode & moduloMask;

        for (ValueNode<K, V> node = valueNodes[inputValueIndex];
                node != null;
                node = node.next) {
            if (node.mapping.valueHashCode == inputValueHashCode 
                    && Objects.equals(node.mapping.value, value)) {
                return node;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to access the value node containing the given value. This 
     * version does not compute the hash code of the input value but rather uses 
     * the hash code given in the second argument.
     * 
     * @param value         the target value.
     * @param valueHashCode the hash code of the value.
     * @return a value node containing the given value or {@code null} if there
     *         is no such.
     */
    private ValueNode<K, V> accessValueNode(Object value, int valueHashCode) {
        int inputValueIndex = valueHashCode & moduloMask;

        for (ValueNode<K, V> node = valueNodes[inputValueIndex];
                node != null;
                node = node.next) {
            if (node.mapping.valueHashCode == valueHashCode
                    && Objects.equals(node.mapping.value, value)) {
                return node;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Appends {@code valueNode} to the tail of the value node iteration list.
     * 
     * @param valueNode the value node to append.
     */
    private void appendValueNodeToIterationList(ValueNode<K, V> valueNode) {
        if (valueNode.up != null) {
            System.out.println("up");
        }

        if (valueNode.down != null) {
            System.out.println("down");
        }

        if (valueIterationTail != null) {
            valueIterationTail.down = valueNode;
            valueNode.up = valueIterationTail;
            valueIterationTail = valueNode;
            valueNode.down = null;
        } else {
            valueIterationHead = valueNode;
            valueIterationTail = valueNode;
            valueNode.up = null;
            valueNode.down = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks the load factor.
     * 
     * @param loadFactor the candidate load factor.
     * @return the input load factor.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the input load factor is too small or
     *                                  is a NaN value.
     */
    private float checkLoadFactor(float loadFactor) {
        if (Float.isNaN(loadFactor)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The load factor is NaN.");
        }

        if (loadFactor <= MINIMUM_LOAD_FACTOR) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The load factor is too small: " + loadFactor + ". " +
                    "Must be at least " + MINIMUM_LOAD_FACTOR + ".");
        }

        return loadFactor;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the key node and its related mapping and value node.
     * 
     * @param keyNode the key node to remove.
     * @return the value of the removed mapping.
     */
    private V doRemove(KeyNode<K, V> keyNode) {
        Mapping<K, V> mapping = keyNode.mapping;
        ValueNode<K, V> valueNode = accessValueNode(mapping.value, 
                                                    mapping.valueHashCode);
        unlinkKeyNodeFromIterationList(keyNode);
        unlinkKeyNodeFromCollisionChain(keyNode);
        unlinkValueNodeFromIterationList(valueNode);
        unlinkValueNodeFromCollisionChain(valueNode);

        return mapping.value;
    }

    /**
     * Makes the internal key and value tables twice as large as they are and
     * relinks all the mappings to the new larger tables.
     */
    private void expand() {
        KeyNode<K, V>[] newKeyNodes = new KeyNode[keyNodes.length << 1];
        ValueNode<K, V>[] newValueNodes = new ValueNode[newKeyNodes.length];

        for (KeyNode<K, V> node = keyIterationHead; 
                node != null;
                node = node.down) {
            insertKeyNode(node, newKeyNodes);
        }

        for (ValueNode<K, V> node = valueIterationHead;
                node != null;
                node = node.down) {
            insertValueNode(node, newValueNodes);
        }

        this.keyNodes = newKeyNodes;
        this.valueNodes = newValueNodes;
        this.moduloMask = newKeyNodes.length - 1;
    }

    /**
     * Makes sure the capacity is no smaller than {@code MINIMUM_CAPACITY} and 
     * is a power of two.
     * 
     * @param capacity the requested capacity.
     * @return the actual capacity.
     */
    private int fixCapacity(int capacity) {
        capacity = Math.max(capacity, MINIMUM_CAPACITY);

        int actualCapacity = 1;

        while (actualCapacity < capacity) {
            actualCapacity <<= 1;
        }

        return actualCapacity;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the given key node to its correct location in 
     * {@code newKeyNodes}.
     * 
     * @param keyNode     the key node to insert.
     * @param newKeyNodes the new key node table.
     */
    private void insertKeyNode(KeyNode<K, V> keyNode, 
                               KeyNode<K, V>[] newKeyNodes) {
        int newModuloMask = newKeyNodes.length - 1;
        int index = keyNode.mapping.keyHashCode & newModuloMask;

        if (newKeyNodes[index] == null) {
            newKeyNodes[index] = keyNode;
            keyNode.next = null;
        } else {
            keyNode.next = newKeyNodes[index];
            newKeyNodes[index].prev = keyNode;
            newKeyNodes[index] = keyNode;
        }

        keyNode.prev = null;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the given value node to its correct location in 
     * {@code newValueNodes}.
     * 
     * @param valueNode     the value node to insert.
     * @param newValueNodes the new value node table.
     */
    private void insertValueNode(ValueNode<K, V> valueNode,
                                 ValueNode<K, V>[] newValueNodes) {
        int newModuloMask = newValueNodes.length - 1;
        int index = valueNode.mapping.valueHashCode & newModuloMask;

        if (newValueNodes[index] == null) {
            newValueNodes[index] = valueNode;
            valueNode.next = null;
        } else {
            valueNode.next = newValueNodes[index];
            newValueNodes[index].prev = valueNode;
            newValueNodes[index] = valueNode;
        }

        valueNode.prev = null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns {@code true} if the data structure is sufficiently large for
     * making the internal tables larger.
     * 
     * @return {@code true} if the data structure should expand.
     */
    private boolean isFull() {
        return size > (int)(loadFactor * keyNodes.length);
    }

    /**
     * Prepends {@code valueNode} to the head of a collision chain of 
     * {@code newValue}.
     * 
     * @param valueNode the target value node.
     * @param newValue  the new value for the value node.
     */
    private void prependValueNodeToCollisionChain(ValueNode<K, V> valueNode,
                                                  V newValue) {
        int newValueHashCode = Objects.hashCode(newValue);
        int newValueIndex = newValueHashCode & moduloMask;

        if (valueNodes[newValueIndex] != null) {
            valueNodes[newValueIndex].prev = valueNode;
            valueNode.next = valueNodes[newValueIndex];
            valueNodes[newValueIndex] = valueNode;
        } else {
            valueNodes[newValueIndex] = valueNode;
        }

        valueNode.mapping.value = newValue;
        valueNode.mapping.valueHashCode = newValueHashCode;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts a new non-existent key/value mapping to this hash map.
     * @param key   the key of the mapping.
     * @param value the value of the mapping.
     */
    private void putNonExisting(K key, V value) {
        Mapping<K, V> mapping = new Mapping<>(key, value);
        KeyNode<K, V> keyNode = new KeyNode<>(mapping);
        ValueNode<K, V> valueNode = new ValueNode<>(mapping);

        // Link in the iteration list:
        if (size == 0) {
            keyIterationHead = keyNode;
            keyIterationTail = keyNode;

            valueIterationHead = valueNode;
            valueIterationTail = valueNode;
        } else {
            keyIterationTail.down = keyNode;
            keyNode.up = keyIterationTail;
            keyIterationTail = keyNode;

            valueIterationTail.down = valueNode;
            valueNode.up = valueIterationTail;
            valueIterationTail = valueNode;
        }

        // Add the key node and the value node to the beginning of their
        // respective collision chains:
        int keyIndex = mapping.keyHashCode & moduloMask;
        int valueIndex = mapping.valueHashCode & moduloMask;

        if (keyNodes[keyIndex] == null) {
            keyNodes[keyIndex] = keyNode;
        } else {
            keyNode.next = keyNodes[keyIndex];
            keyNodes[keyIndex].prev = keyNode;
            keyNodes[keyIndex] = keyNode;
        }

        if (valueNodes[valueIndex] == null) {
            valueNodes[valueIndex] = valueNode;
        } else {
            valueNode.next = valueNodes[valueIndex];
            valueNodes[valueIndex].prev = valueNode;
            valueNodes[valueIndex] = valueNode;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes the given key node from the key iteration list.
     * 
     * @param keyNode the target key node to remove.
     */
    private void unlinkKeyNodeFromIterationList(KeyNode<K, V> keyNode) {
        if (keyNode.up != null) {
            keyNode.up.down = keyNode.down;
        } else {
            keyIterationHead = keyIterationHead.down;

            if (keyIterationHead != null) {
                keyIterationHead.up = null;
            }
        }

        if (keyNode.down != null) {
            keyNode.down.up = keyNode.up;
        } else {
            keyIterationTail = keyIterationTail.up;

            if (keyIterationTail != null) {
                keyIterationTail.down = null;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes the given key node from its current collision chain.
     * 
     * @param keyNode the target key node to remove.
     */
    private void unlinkKeyNodeFromCollisionChain(KeyNode<K, V> keyNode) {
        if (keyNode.prev != null) {
            keyNode.prev.next = keyNode.next;
        } else {
            int keyNodeIndex = keyNode.mapping.keyHashCode & moduloMask;
            keyNodes[keyNodeIndex] = keyNode.next;

            if (keyNodes[keyNodeIndex] != null) {
                keyNodes[keyNodeIndex].prev = null;
            }
        }

        if (keyNode.next != null) {
            keyNode.next.prev = keyNode.prev;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes the given value node from the value iteration list.
     * 
     * @param valueNode the target value node to remove.
     */
    private void unlinkValueNodeFromCollisionChain(ValueNode<K, V> valueNode) {
        if (valueNode.prev != null) {
            valueNode.prev.next = valueNode.next;
        } else {
            int valueNodeIndex = valueNode.mapping.valueHashCode & moduloMask;
            valueNodes[valueNodeIndex] = valueNode.next;

            if (valueNodes[valueNodeIndex] != null) {
                valueNodes[valueNodeIndex].prev = null;
            }
        }

        if (valueNode.next != null) {
            valueNode.next.prev = valueNode.prev;
        } 
    }

    /**
     * Removes the given value node from its current collision chain.
     * 
     * @param valueNode the target value node to remove.
     */
    private void unlinkValueNodeFromIterationList(ValueNode<K, V> valueNode) {
        if (valueNode.up != null) {
            valueNode.up.down = valueNode.down;
        } else {
            valueIterationHead = valueIterationHead.down;

            if (valueIterationHead != null) {
                valueIterationHead.up = null;
            }
        }

        if (valueNode.down != null) {
            valueNode.down.up = valueNode.up;
        } else {
            valueIterationTail = valueIterationTail.up;

            if (valueIterationTail != null) {
                valueIterationTail.down = null;
            } 
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the value associated with {@code keyNode}.
     * 
     * @param keyNode  the target key node.
     * @param newValue the new value for the key node.
     * @return the old value associated with the given key node.
     */
    private V updateValue(KeyNode<K, V> keyNode, V newValue) {
        V oldValue = keyNode.mapping.value;
        ValueNode<K, V> valueNode = 
                accessValueNode(oldValue,
                                keyNode.mapping.valueHashCode);

        unlinkValueNodeFromIterationList(valueNode);
        appendValueNodeToIterationList(valueNode);
        unlinkValueNodeFromCollisionChain(valueNode);
        prependValueNodeToCollisionChain(valueNode, newValue);
        return oldValue;
    }

    /**
     * This class implements the inverse view mapping values to keys.
     */
    private final class InverseMap extends StubMap<V, K> {

        @Override
        public K get(Object value) {
            ValueNode<K, V> valueNode = accessValueNode(value);
            return valueNode != null ? valueNode.mapping.key : null;
        }

        private final class KeySet extends StubSet<V> {

            private final class KeySetIterator implements Iterator<V> {

                private final int expectedModCount = modificationCount;
                private int iterated = 0;
                private ValueNode<K, V> entry = valueIterationHead;

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    checkModificationCount();
                    return iterated < size;
                }

                @Override
                public V next() {
                    checkModificationCount();

                    if (!hasNext()) {
                        throw new NoSuchElementException();
                    }

                    ValueNode<K, V> valueNode = entry;
                    entry = entry.down;
                    iterated++;
                    return valueNode.mapping.value;
                }

                private void checkModificationCount() {
                    if (expectedModCount != modificationCount) {
                        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public KeySetIterator iterator() {
                return new KeySetIterator();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Set<V> keySet() {
            return new KeySet();
        }

        @Override
        public K put(V value, K key) {
            if (isFull()) {
                expand();
            }

            ValueNode<K, V> valueNode = accessValueNode(value);
            K oldKey;

            if (valueNode == null) {
                putNonExisting(key, value);
                oldKey = null;
                size++;
            } else {
                oldKey = updateKey(valueNode, key);
            }

            modificationCount++;
            return oldKey;
        }

        @Override
        public void putAll(Map<? extends V, ? extends K> m) {
            for (Map.Entry<? extends V, ? extends K> e : m.entrySet()) {
                put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public K remove(Object value) {
            ValueNode<K, V> valueNode = accessValueNode(value);

            if (valueNode == null) {
                return null;
            }

            size--;
            modificationCount++;
            return doRemove(valueNode);
        }

        /**
         * Appends the given key node to the tail of the key iteration list.
         * 
         * @param keyNode the target key node to append.
         */
        private void appendKeyNodeToIterationList(KeyNode<K, V> keyNode) {
            if (keyIterationTail != null) {
                keyIterationTail.down = keyNode;
                keyNode.up = keyIterationTail;
                keyIterationTail = keyNode;
                keyNode.down = null;
            } else {
                keyIterationHead = keyNode;
                keyIterationTail = keyNode;
                keyNode.up = null;
                keyNode.down = null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Removes the value node and its related mapping and key node from this
         * data structure.
         * 
         * @param valueNode the target value node.
         * @return the key of the mapping removed.
         */
        private K doRemove(ValueNode<K, V> valueNode) {
            Mapping<K, V> mapping = valueNode.mapping;
            KeyNode<K, V> keyNode = accessKeyNode(mapping.key,
                                                  mapping.keyHashCode);

            unlinkKeyNodeFromIterationList(keyNode);
            unlinkKeyNodeFromCollisionChain(keyNode);
            unlinkValueNodeFromIterationList(valueNode);
            unlinkValueNodeFromCollisionChain(valueNode);

            return mapping.key;
        }

        /**
         * Inserts the given key node to the beginning of a collision chain 
         * associated with {@code newKey}.
         * 
         * @param keyNode the target key node.
         * @param newKey  the new key.
         */
        private void prependKeyNodeToCollisionChain(KeyNode<K, V> keyNode, 
                                                    K newKey) {
            int newKeyHashCode = Objects.hashCode(newKey);
            int newKeyIndex = newKeyHashCode & moduloMask;

            if (keyNodes[newKeyIndex] != null) {
                keyNodes[newKeyIndex].prev = keyNode;
                keyNode.next = keyNodes[newKeyIndex];
                keyNodes[newKeyIndex] = keyNode;
            } else {
                keyNodes[newKeyIndex] = keyNode;
            }

            keyNode.mapping.key = newKey;
            keyNode.mapping.keyHashCode = newKeyHashCode;
        }

        /**
         * Updates the key associated with the given value node.
         * 
         * @param valueNode the target value node.
         * @param newKey    the new key.
         * @return the old key.
         */
        private K updateKey(ValueNode<K, V> valueNode, K newKey) {
            K oldKey = valueNode.mapping.key;
            KeyNode<K, V> keyNode = 
                    accessKeyNode(oldKey, valueNode.mapping.keyHashCode);

            unlinkKeyNodeFromIterationList(keyNode);
            appendKeyNodeToIterationList(keyNode);
            unlinkKeyNodeFromCollisionChain(keyNode);
            prependKeyNodeToCollisionChain(keyNode, newKey);
            return oldKey;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This inner class implements a view over entries.
     */
    private final class EntrySet extends StubSet<Entry<K, V>> {

        /**
         * This inner class implements an iterator over a set of entries.
         */
        private final class EntrySetIterator implements Iterator<Entry<K, V>> {

            private final int expectedModCount = modificationCount;
            private int iterated = 0;
            private KeyNode<K, V> entry = keyIterationHead;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                checkModificationCount();
                return iterated < size;
            }

            @Override
            public Entry<K, V> next() {
                checkModificationCount();

                if (!hasNext()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }

                KeyNode<K, V> keyNode = entry;
                entry = entry.down;
                iterated++;
                return keyNode.mapping;
            }

            private void checkModificationCount() {
                if (expectedModCount != modificationCount) {
                    throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<Entry<K, V>> iterator() {
            return new EntrySetIterator();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> map = new BidirectionalHashMap<>();

        map.put(1, "one");
        map.put(2, "two");
        map.put(3, "three");
        map.put(4, "four");

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**StubMap.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class is a stub for the {@link java.util.Map} interface.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 24, 2017)
 * @param <K> the key type.
 * @param <V> the value type.
 */
public abstract class StubMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();    
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();    
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

**StubSet.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This abstract class is the stub for the {@link java.util.Set} interface.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 24, 2017)
 * @param <E> the element type.
 */
public abstract class StubSet<E> implements Set<E> {

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {    
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();    
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

**BidirectionalHashMapTest.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.ConcurrentModificationException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class BidirectionalHashMapTest {

    private BidirectionalHashMap<Integer, Integer> map;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        map = new BidirectionalHashMap<>();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSize() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            assertEquals(i, map.size());
            map.put(i, i);
            assertEquals(i + 1, map.size());
        }
    } 

    @Test
    public void testIsEmpty() {
        assertTrue(map.isEmpty());
        map.remove(4);
        assertTrue(map.isEmpty());
        map.put(1, 1);
        assertFalse(map.isEmpty());
        map.put(2, 2);
        assertFalse(map.isEmpty());
        map.remove(2);
        assertFalse(map.isEmpty());
        map.remove(3);
        assertFalse(map.isEmpty());
        map.remove(1);
        assertTrue(map.isEmpty());
        map.remove(-1);
        assertTrue(map.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
            map.put(i, i + 100);
        }

        for (int i = 49; i >= 0; --i) {
            assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(i + 100), map.get(i));
        }

        for (int i = 50; i < 100; ++i) {
            assertNull(map.get(i));
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testContainsKey() {
        map.put(1, 11);
        map.put(2, 12);

        assertTrue(map.containsKey(1));
        assertTrue(map.containsKey(2));
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(11));
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(12));
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(0));
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(3));

        map.remove(2);

        assertTrue(map.containsKey(1));
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testContainsValue() {
        map.put(1, 11);
        map.put(2, 12);

        assertTrue(map.containsValue(11));
        assertTrue(map.containsValue(12));
        assertFalse(map.containsValue(1));
        assertFalse(map.containsValue(2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPut() {
        for (int i = 10; i < 60; ++i) {
            map.put(i, 2 * i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            assertFalse(map.containsKey(i));
        }

        for (int i = 10; i < 60; ++i) {
            assertTrue(map.containsKey(i));
            assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(2 * i), map.get(i));
        }

        for (int i = 60; i < 100; ++i) {
            assertFalse(map.containsKey(i));
            assertNull(map.get(i));
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testRemove() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            assertNull(map.remove(i));
            assertTrue(map.isEmpty());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            assertEquals(i, map.size());
            map.put(i, i + 3);
            assertEquals(i + 1, map.size());
        }

        for (int i = 99; i >= 0; --i) {
            assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(i + 3), map.remove(i));
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testClear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
            map.put(i, i + 1);
        }

        assertEquals(200, map.size());
        map.clear();
        assertEquals(0, map.size());
        assertTrue(map.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEntrySet1() {
        map.put(10, 100);
        map.put(3, 30);
        map.put(5, 50);
        map.put(1, 10);

        Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> entrySet = map.entrySet();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> iterator = entrySet.iterator();
        Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e;

        assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
        e = iterator.next();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(10), e.getKey());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(100), e.getValue());

        assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
        e = iterator.next();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(3), e.getKey());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(30), e.getValue());

        assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
        e = iterator.next();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(5), e.getKey());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(50), e.getValue());

        assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
        e = iterator.next();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(1), e.getKey());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(10), e.getValue());

        assertFalse(iterator.hasNext());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEntrySet2() {
        map.put(10, 100);
        map.put(3, 30);
        map.put(5, 50);
        map.put(1, 10);

        map.put(3, 40);

        Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> iterator = 
                map.entrySet().iterator();

        Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e;

        assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
        e = iterator.next();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(10), e.getKey());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(100), e.getValue());

        assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
        e = iterator.next();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(3), e.getKey());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(40), e.getValue());

        assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
        e = iterator.next();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(5), e.getKey());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(50), e.getValue());

        assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
        e = iterator.next();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(1), e.getKey());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(10), e.getValue());
    }

    @Test(expected = ConcurrentModificationException.class)
    public void testEntrySetThrowsOnComodification() {
        map.put(1, 1);
        map.put(2, 2);

        Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> iterator =
                map.entrySet().iterator();

        iterator.next();
        map.remove(1);
        iterator.next();
    }

    @Test
    public void testInverseGet() {
        BidirectionalHashMap<Integer, String> map =
                new BidirectionalHashMap<>();

        map.put(1, "1");
        map.put(2, "2");
        map.put(4, "4");

        assertNull(map.inverseMap().get("a"));
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(1), map.inverseMap().get("1"));
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(2), map.inverseMap().get("2"));
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(4), map.inverseMap().get("4"));

        map.put(2, "22");

        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(2), map.inverseMap().get("22"));
        assertNull(map.inverseMap().get("2"));
        assertEquals("22", map.get(2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testInversePut() {
        BidirectionalHashMap<Integer, String> map = 
                new BidirectionalHashMap<>();

        map.inverseMap().put("1", 1);
        map.inverseMap().put("2", 2);

        assertTrue(map.containsValue("1"));
        assertTrue(map.containsValue("2"));
        assertTrue(map.containsKey(1));
        assertTrue(map.containsKey(2));

        assertEquals("1", map.get(1));
        assertEquals("2", map.get(2));
        assertNull(map.get(3));
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(1), map.inverseMap().get("1"));
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(2), map.inverseMap().get("2"));
        assertNull(map.inverseMap().get("3"));

        map.inverseMap().put("2", 22);
        assertNull(map.get(2));
        assertEquals("2", map.get(22));
    }

    @Test
    public void testInverseRemove() {
        map.put(1, 11);
        map.put(2, 12);
        map.put(4, 14);

        map.remove(2);
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(2));
        map.inverseMap().remove(15);
        assertEquals(2, map.size());
        map.inverseMap().remove(11);
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(1));
        assertEquals(1, map.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testOrder() {
        map.put(1, 101);
        map.put(2, 102);
        map.put(3, 103);
        map.put(4, 104);
        map.inverseMap().put(102, -2);

        Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> iterator =
                map.entrySet().iterator();

        assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
        Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e = iterator.next();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(1), e.getKey());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(101), e.getValue());

        assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
        e = iterator.next();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(3), e.getKey());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(103), e.getValue());

        assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
        e = iterator.next();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(4), e.getKey());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(104), e.getValue());

        assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
        e = iterator.next();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(-2), e.getKey());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(102), e.getValue());
        assertFalse(iterator.hasNext());

        BidirectionalHashMap<String, Integer> map2 = 
                new BidirectionalHashMap<>();

        map2.put("1", 1);
        map2.put("2", 2);
        map2.put("3", 3);
        map2.put("4", 4); // (1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4)

        map2.put("1", 5); // (2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5)

        Iterator<Integer> inverseKeySetIterator = 
                map2.inverseMap().keySet().iterator();

        assertTrue(inverseKeySetIterator.hasNext());
        Integer i = inverseKeySetIterator.next();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(2), i);

        assertTrue(inverseKeySetIterator.hasNext());
        i = inverseKeySetIterator.next();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(3), i);

        assertTrue(inverseKeySetIterator.hasNext());
        i = inverseKeySetIterator.next();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(4), i);

        assertTrue(inverseKeySetIterator.hasNext());
        i = inverseKeySetIterator.next();
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(5), i);
    }
}
```

## Critique request

Please tell me anything that comes to mind, ho ho ho.

Answer (score 2):

it could be done in much less code out of 2 maps: `HashMap<K,V>` and `HashMap<V, List<K>>`.

Comment: `HashMap<V, K>`, I believe.

Comment: `HashMap<V, Collection<K>>` maybe. Generally, different keys can be mapped on the same value. So one value corresponds to a set of keys.

Comment: Also, it's already available from either Guava or Apache Commons Collections.